# Fermats last theorem follows if one can prove it for odd primes and $4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

In our lecture notes its written that fermats last theorem, i.e.

$x^n+y^n=z^n, n\in \mathbb Z\text{ has no non-trivial solutions}$

only needs to be proven for every odd prime $p$ and $n=4$.

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $n$ is composite, let $n=ij$, we can write

$$x^{ij}+y^{ij}=z^{ij}$$ or

$$(x^i)^j+(y^i)^j=(z^i)^j$$

or

$$X^j+Y^j=Z^j.$$

So if the theorem holds for a composite exponent, it holds for its factors (except $2$).

The case of $4$ must be handled explicitly because both of its factors are $2$.

Answer (score 2):

Every $n \geq 3$ is either divisible by $4$ or by an odd prime $p$. From the exponential laws it follows that every $n$-th power is then a $4$-th power or a $p$-th power. Explicitly, if we have $n = 4m$, then $x^n+y^n=z^n$ is equivalent to $(x^m)^4+(y^m)^4=(z^m)^4$, so any non-trivial solution for a number divisible by $4$ will give rise to a non-trivial solution for $n=4$. This works analogously with $4$ replaced by $p$.